# Sales growth by product category

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help in finding the Sales Growth by Product Category last year

Table looks like this

```
Tablename- SUPERSTOREDATABASE   

|----------|---------------|--------|-------------|----------|-----------|-----------|
| OrderID  |ProductCategory| Date   |ProductName  | Sales    |Quantity   | Profit    |
|----------|---------------|--------|-------------|----------|-----------|-----------|
|    12    |   Furniture   |2/2/2018|    Table    |     $30  |    2      |      10   |
|----------|---------------|--------|-------------|----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Returns table: I am tryin to exclude retuned items

```
|------------------|-------------------|
| OrderID          |     Returned      |
|------------------|-------------------|
|    2             |        Yes        |
|------------------|-------------------|
```

I need to write to query to get this output

```
|------------------|-------------------|
| ProductCategory  |Year on Year Growth|
|------------------|-------------------|
|    Furniture     |        35%        |
|------------------|-------------------|
```

Please help me write a query

I tried the code below,but its not working

```
select year(ORDERS.ORDERDATE) as year,
      sum(case when year(ORDERS.ORDERDATE) = 2019 then ORDERS.SALES else 0 end) as price_2019,
      sum(case when year(ORDERS.ORDERDATE) = 2018 then ORDERS.SALES else 0 end) as price_2018
from  SUPERSTOREDATABASE.PUBLIC.ORDERS
left join SUPERSTOREDATABASE.PUBLIC.RETURN on ORDERS.ORDERID = RETURN.ORDERID
group by year(ORDERS.ORDERDATE)
order by max(year(ORDERS.ORDERDATE));
```

Comment: You describe one table.  Your query has two.  You haven't defined what you mean by YOY growth, nor the issues with your query.

Comment: Sorry just edited

Answer (score 0):

> I need help in finding the Sales Growth by Product Category last year

If I understand correctly, you just need to adjust your query for the product category:

```
select o.product_category
       sum(case when year(o.ORDERDATE) = 2019 then o.SALES else 0 end) as price_2019,
       sum(case when year(o.ORDERDATE) = 2018 then o.SALES else 0 end) as price_2018,
        (-1 +
         sum(case when year(o.ORDERDATE) = 2019 then o.SALES else 0 end) /
         sum(case when year(o.ORDERDATE) = 2018 then o.SALES else 0 end)
        ) as yoy_growth
from  SUPERSTOREDATABASE.PUBLIC.ORDERS o
group by o.product_category
order by o.product_category
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you include returns table too? I am getting a different answer from what I did manually on excel

Comment: @user2830993 . . . I think this answers the question that you asked here and I also think you have asked another question already,.

Comment: Yes! Me and my friend are solving some questions. We are not sure of the logic to find average revenue per sale. Please check if you can help with that.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68354458/average-revenue-per-sale